# Perl: Access hash elements within a hash ref

Tags: perl, hash

How would I go about accessing the elements of this hash_ref within a foreach loop?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $services = {
    ftp    => { port => 21,   pr => "",                      waitfor => '/220/'      },
    ssh    => { port => 22,   pr => "",                      waitfor => '/SSH/'      },
    domain => { port => 42,   pr => "",                      waitfor => ''           },
    http   => { port => 80,   pr => "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n\n",   waitfor => '/200/'      },
    https  => { port => 443,  pr => "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n\n",   waitfor => '/200/'      },
    pop3    => { port => 110, pr => "",                      waitfor => '/\+OK/'     },
    imap   => { port => 143,  pr => "",                      waitfor => '/OK/'       },
    smtp   => { port => 25,   pr => "",                      waitfor => '/SMTP/'     }
};


foreach my $key (keys %{ $services }) {
    my $port    = $service{port};
    my $waitfor = $services->{$service}->{waitfor};
}
```

For FTP for instance I want to assign FTP to a scalar and then each key from FTP (port, pr, waitfor) to scalars as well within the foreach loop that cycles between the services (ftp,ssh,dns,etc...)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $waitfor = $services->{$service}->{waitfor};
```

should be

```
my $waitfor = $services->{$key}->{waitfor};
```

Or you can use something like:

```
for my $id (keys %$services) {
   my $service = $services->{$id};

   my $port    = $service->{port};
   my $waitfor = $service->{waitfor};
   ...
}
```

Or even

```
for my $service (values %$services) {
   my $port    = $service->{port};
   my $waitfor = $service->{waitfor};
   ...
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly (used 3rd version), and more importantly I see where I was misunderstanding my usage.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this easily..

```
foreach my $service (keys %$services)   {
print "serivce = $service \n";
foreach my $types (keys %$services->{$service}) {
    print "$services->{$service}->{$types} \n";
}
```

}